# SQL functions with parameters returning multiple rows in one function call

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

need some help with this SQL function. When I run my query thru the console I get back multiple rows as a result

```
select user_id
from snacks
where completed_at between _start_date and _end_date
group by 1
```

But when I call the function below, I only get one row as result. Is there a way I can get multiple rows in **one** function call, passing only **_start_date** and **_end_date** as parameters? The result I need is a table written in CSV format. Have successfully managed to return multiple rows with `SELECT COALESCE(json_agg(row_to_json(data.*)), '[]'::json)`
but the result I want needs to be in CSV format (with headers).

```
 create function snacks_per_day(_start_date date, _end_date date)
    returns table(user_id text)
        language sql
    as
    $$
        with data as (
            select user_id
            from snacks
            where completed_at between _start_date and _end_date
            group by 1
        ) 
        SELECT data.user_id from data
    $$;
```

Comment: According to the online docs, MySQL Functions can't return tables.  Are you sure it's MySQL and/or that the code here is exactly what you used?  *(This would run in Postgres, for example, but not MySQL.)*

Comment: yea, I'm running it on Postgres, but language is as stated SQL (not MySQL sry :) )

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with your function.  You imply that you then use `row_to_json()`, but that will ***only*** work if you pass in ***more*** than one column.  Please see the following example on dbfiddle, edit that example to show your problem case, then edit your question here with the full details needed to replicate your problem case: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=09995e7266b89865386d7d62db5eb1b1

Comment: How exactly are you calling the function? A set returning function must be used like a table, e.g. `select * from snaks_per_day(...)`

Comment: @MatBailie yea, I have more than one column. But I got a question about the number of returned rows. In dbfiddle I can see you are calling function like this `select * from snacks_per_day('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31')`. Is it possible to nest this functionality into a function? So a function returns all possible rows that SELECT found? (without the need of  `SELECT * from snacks_per_day('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31')`).

Comment: Update your question with an example.  Don't ask questions in comments.  Ideally edit your question to give a full and complete example that can be replicated in dbfiddle.  *(It's not clear what you mean `nest this functionality into a function`; it already **is** in a function...  It's also not clear what you want to do with the results, or what `returns all possible rows that SELECT found` means...  **Create A Concrete Example : Create Dummy Data, Show The Desired Results.**  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example )*

Comment: Please share function calling code.

Comment: Thx everyone for help. I managed to solve this problem with the change of calling function where I used: `select * from snacks_per_day('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31')`. Now have all the data that I need. Thanks once more.